# I can't find the initializer `()` for the grammar production "initializer" in the C++ grammar

Tags: c++, initialization, language-lawyer

[[dcl.init]/(7.1)](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.init#general-7.1):

> If T is a (possibly cv-qualified) class type ([class]), constructors
> are considered. The applicable constructors are enumerated
> ([over.match.ctor]), and the best one for the [initializer](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.init#nt:initializer) () is
> chosen through overload resolution ([over.match]). The constructor
> thus selected is called, with an empty argument list, to initialize
> the object.

I can't find in the grammar an [*initializer*](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.init#nt:initializer) that is equal to `()`. What am I missing?

Comment: https://github.com/cplusplus/draft/issues/2846

Comment: @LanguageLawyer Thank you for the link.